# LAPACK zgemm op(A) dimension

Tags: c++, matrix, lapack, lapacke

In [this](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/zgemm.f.html) link from netlib it specifies M as:

> On entry,  M  specifies  the number  of rows  of the  matrix
>              op( A )  and of the  matrix  C.  M  must  be at least  zero.
>              Unchanged on exit.

So if I want to use a 3x10 matrix as A but I want to use it's conjugate for zgemm (TRANSA = 'C') what should I enter as M? 3 or 10?

Also when I used other LAPACK routines I entered 2D matrices as 1D like A[3*3] instead of A[3][3] and upon calling the routine I just used A for the matrix, Can I do the same with non-square matrices? A[3*10] instead of A[3][10]?

I code in C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A/ Naming convention/clarification**

Before giving an answer and for a better clarity It is important to have this fact in mind:

- in USA, M is used for row size and N for column size

whereas

- in some other places, like Europe, this is the reverse N is for row size and M is for column size

Comments:

- All the Blas/Lapack doc you will find in netlib.org use the USA convention
- I (as a European) must admit that the USA convention is more logical like  indices (i,j) and (m,n) follow the **same alphabetical order**

To avoid such ambiguity I generally use:

- **I_size for row size** and **J_size for column size**

**B/ Answers**

**B.1/ gemm**

```
void cblas_zgemm(CBLAS_LAYOUT layout,
                 CBLAS_TRANSPOSE opA,
                 CBLAS_TRANSPOSE opB,
                 const int M, <-------------- I_Size of op(A) 
                 const int N, <-------------- J_Size of op(B)
                 const int K, <-------------- J_Size of op(A)
                 const void* alpha,
                 const void* A,
                 const int lda,
                 const void* B,
                 const int ldb,
                 const void* beta,
                 void* C,
                 const int ldc);
```

In verbs if **TRANSA = 'T'** you must take the dimensions of the **transposed** A matrix.

The implementation to call `cblas_zgemm` may look like:

```
const Size_t opA_I_size = (opA == CblasNoTrans) ? A.I_size() : A.J_size();
const Size_t opA_J_size = (opA == CblasNoTrans) ? A.J_size() : A.I_size();

const Size_t opB_I_size = (opB == CblasNoTrans) ? B.I_size() : B.J_size();
const Size_t opB_J_size = (opB == CblasNoTrans) ? B.J_size() : B.I_size();

cblas_zgemm(CblasColMajor,
            opA,
            opB,
            opA_I_size,
            opB_J_size,
            opA_J_size,
            alpha,
            A.data(),
            A.ld(),
            B.data(),
            B.ld(),
            beta,
            C.data(),
            C.ld());
```

**B.2/ Memory layout**

You must also take memory layout into account. There are two possibilities :

- column major (Fortran style) you must allocate an array of size `ld*J_size` and Aᵢⱼ is `A[i+ld*j]` with 0 ≤ i < I_size and 0 ≤ j < J_size
- row major (C style) you must allocate an array of size `I_size*ld` and Aᵢⱼ is `A[j+ld*i]` with 0 ≤ i < I_size and 0 ≤ j < J_size

(where **ld** is the leading dimension)

**Updates:**

- Even if you are coding in C++ **I recommend to use the Fortran convention (column major)**. [Lapacke](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/tree/master/LAPACKE) pretends to support row major mode too however, under the hood, it simply **copies** your matrix into a column major layout before calling the requested subroutine. So this extra facility is only an illusion (concerning perfs). To be more precise this is the [LAPACKE_dge_trans() function](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d6/d5e/lapacke__dge__trans_8c_aef756b447ef9a87b2b776f00735555b3.html#aef756b447ef9a87b2b776f00735555b3). You can check Lapacke code to see that this function is used nearly everywhere as soon as `Layout=RowMajor` (see the [lapacke_dgesv_work()](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/blob/5feb8b3f6dda40e0f9d1d72965be6efdbddafb01/LAPACKE/src/lapacke_dgesv_work.c) code for instance).
- Also note that if you want generic strides ("arbitrary leading dimension" in both I and J directions) you can use library like [Blis](https://github.com/flame/blis) instead of **Blas**. The real advantage is to be able to create arbitrary 2D-views of Tensors. This choice depends on your application, I do not know if you have tensor manipulation in mind.

**B.3/ Matrix dimensions**

If your matrices will always be as small as 3x10 blas/lapack is not a good choice (for perfomance). Considere using a library like [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) or [Blaz](https://bitbucket.org/blaze-lib/blaze).

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thank you! My matrices are quite large I was just using 3 and 10 as examples.

Comment: @Alireza I just added some "updates" concerning memory layout / Lapacke (see end of B.2)

Comment: This is an excellent explanation. It's worth noting that you can simplify your thinking quite a bit by observing that M and N are *always* the row and column counts of C, and that K is always the dimension being multiplied over. I find this much, much simpler to keep track of than trying to reason about M and N in terms of the dimensions of A and B, because it's not effected by transpose.

Comment: @StephenCanon I do agree and you are absolutely right. I will clean my post tomorrow as soon as I have some time (I'm a bit in a hurry right now). Thank you for your positive & constructive feedback.

Comment: @PicaudVincent, amazing answer. Would you please be able to comment on the void pointer arguments? That is, ``alpha`` and ``beta``. In C++. If I want alpha to be 1 and beta to be 0, do I declare them as ``std::complex<double> alpha(1.0, 0.0)`` and ``std::complex<double> beta(0.0, 0.0)`` and pass to ``cblas_zgemm(...)`` as ``&alpha`` and ``&beta``? And this way I obtain in C (letter, not language) memory-buffer  
 the result of A * B (my aim is to multiply 2 complex matrices together and obtain the result in the third)? Thank you!

Comment: @velenos14 Thank you. Yes, for complex routines, scalars must also be of complex type, even if the imaginary part is zero. The purpose of `void *` is precisely to support any complex type, the `std::complex<double>` of C++ or the `double complex` of C99 for instance. The only restriction is that a complex type must store two floating-point numbers (real and imaginary parts) contiguously in memory.

Comment: @PicaudVincent, thank you, I appreciate your input.